# Payment via Braintree in flutter application

Tags: flutter, paypal-sandbox, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I am building a marketplace app and want to include payment via PayPal with Braintree (see documentation: [flutter_braintree](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_braintree)). Right now I am working with a braintree sandbox trial account.
As far as I am understanding it correctly, I have to save the braintree `tokenizationKey` for every company to enable payments directly to them and not to the marketplace. Due to test reasons I included the `tokenizationKey` of my braintree sandbox account.
I am successfully directed to the PayPal checkout page where I can't login since it's in sandbox mode. When I select "proceed with sandbox purchase" I am then redirected to the application and do receive a `BraintreePaymentMethodNonce`.
[Here you can find the screen where I can't login.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBo1g.jpg)

But somehow I can't see any transactions in the dashboard of my sandbox account.
Am I mistaken with the way tokenization works or where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am successfully directed to the PayPal checkout where I can't login since it's in sandbox mode.

Use a sandbox buyer (personal) account from https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts%2F

---

If the companies only have PayPal accounts rather than Braintree accounts, you can use [PayPal via Braintree](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/braintree-integration/) and a braintree `access_token` from PayPal for authentication to get the client token on your server (no tokenizationKey)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am not able to use a sandbox buyer account since I am not allowed to Login. Or what do you mean by using a sandbox buyer account?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to log in to, but a sandbox buyer account is used to complete a regular sandbox PayPal checkout.

Comment: I thought I might be able to model the whole payment process. So that I would have been able to login at the screen (see attached picture in original post) with a sandbox buyer account and then complete the payment. 

I'm just able to click "proceed with sandbox purchase" and then get redirected to the app with a nonce. But no transactions are shown in the braintree sandbox account. I feel like I get something very wrong.

Comment: That's a mock flow, no actual transactions on the PayPal side. Set your environment to sandbox.  But since you aren't seeing transactions in Braintree, the issue may be that you aren't creating one after the return.  A BraintreePaymentMethodNonce is not a transaction; when approved it's used to submit one for settlement.

Comment: I am sorry to ask you all this, but as you can see in the documentation of [flutter_braintree](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_braintree/latest/index.html), there ist no further description after creating the BraintreePaymentMethodNonce. 

You said the issue might be that I'm not creating a transaction. But how would I do that? 
Thank you :)

Comment: On your server. Read the Braintree documentation, https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/server-side/node

Comment: That was a great help! Somehow I missed that part, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same issue. Now I found the solution. All you have to do is link you braintree sandbox to your paypal sandbox. [Here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/testing-go-live/node#linked-paypal-testing) is the process of linking your sandbox accounts.

Comment: I am having similar issue. I tried to use credit card, the payment got processed but I can't find any transactions in Braintree